# Craft.log showing Buggy iconv installed. Will fallback to mbstring

Tags: string, conversion, requirements

I'm curious if others are seeing a similar error in their Craft logs.  It says:

> Buggy iconv installed.  Will fallback to mbstring.

It's repeated over and over seemingly with almost every request.

It's a pretty simple server, setup using the default setting from Laravel Forge on Digital Ocean.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue, same setup (DO+Laravel Forge).

Comment: What did you install to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iconv is a system C library that converts string encodings, and is generally preferable to PHP’s [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) because it supports significantly more character encodings. However it’s not guaranteed that it will be available, and if it is, some versions of it have a bug that could put it into an infinite loop in certain circumstances. So Craft’s [StringHelper::convertToUTF8()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/StringHelper#convertToUTF8-detail) checks for those things before using it, and logs if it’s not available or a buggy version is installed, before falling back on mb_convert_encoding().

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the update brandon.  Is it worth the effort for me to try and update it on our servers or is any performance hit not really worth it?

Comment: @KeithMancuso I don't think it's so much about a performance hit as much as iconv is just more feature rich, so up to you.

Comment: @KeithMancuso It’s better because it supports more character encodings. Just updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I've seen this warning on several sites as well and been asked by clients why the warning is there. So far, it hasn't been an issue but could this answer be extended to indicate what "more character encodings" means? Are there specific languages or situations we should be aware of that may require using iconv?

Comment: @BenParizek Long story, short... I wouldn't worry about it. We've removed that check for Craft 3. It came from HTMLPurifier originally, but we've never ran into an environment where it was an issue and it's caused more support than it ever solved.